# iPhone:How to implement Push Notification in iPhone like facebook?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement push notification functionality in my apps like Facebook provide us so please tell me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Comment: What do you mean with "...like Facebook."?

Comment: thanks a lot devang but is it required server conncetivity?

Comment: notification will be managed by urban airship. You have to implement their coding only and using urbanairship.com you can send notification to all the users containing your app.

Comment: please provide me tutorial link of urbanairship.com

Comment: check out my links it contains example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Push notification using : http://urbanairship.com/

This are the steps you need to follow : http://urbanairship.com/docs/push_index.html   (Example is also available)

Its very easy to implement.